# How to change the appearance of a Feature.Vector that's already displayed?

Tags: openlayers-2, symbology

I've created a bunch of Feature.Vectors from Point objects and assigned them a Style.  Now I want to dynamically change the appearance of one of the features in real time; e.g., change it from red to blue.  (I am NOT hovering over the feature.)  I've tried changing its Style, then doing refresh() on the layer, or redraw(), etc, and either nothing happens or the feature disappears.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: have you save this problem already?

Answer (score 12):

Redraw method should solve your problem, see my little example: [OpenLayers: modifying feature style](http://jsfiddle.net/_DR_/Udd4e/10/)

UPD: I've modified my example a little bit: [OpenLayers: modifying one feature style](http://jsfiddle.net/_DR_/Udd4e/31/)

Comment: Thanks however this appears to change the appearance of the entire layer, rather than that of a particular *one* of many features in the layer, right?

Comment: Could you look at new example, is it what you need?

Comment: @drnextgis : Nice example. +1

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @drnextgis that redraw will do (+1 for nice sample). Though in your situation, since you want to just redraw a single feature, I would use `feature.layer.drawFeature(feature);` which is presented [in the following sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/SMk8K/).